# how to stubbing nested promise in JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, mocking, stub

hi StackOverflow community
im having problems stub this piece of code for unit testing
it is a nested promise call to mongo to create user then retrieve the user from database

`return database.collection('users').insertOne(request.body)
        .then(response => database.collection('users')
        .find({_id:response.insertedId })
            .limit(1)
            .next());`

can you please tell tell me the best way of going about this 
is it best i separate calls into their own functions or...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `create` method if you create one user at moment. It returns created object.
`return database.collection('users').create(request.body)`

Comment: ohh, I see. You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-mongoose or another mock libraries

Comment: i just tested this.. it does not work.. is that for mongodb or mongoose ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly my take would be to put this in a function like this:

```
const dbOperations = {
 saveUser: (request) => database.collection('users').insertOne(request.body)
        .then(response => database.collection('users')
        .find({_id:response.insertedId })
            .limit(1)
            .next());
}
```

and then you can re-declare like

```
dbOperations.saveUser = (request) => Promise.resolve(request.body);
```

is that what you wanted?